Display total in headline bar, is a trigger my only option despite being read only?
The goal is to add a total to the headline bar in the Accounts layout. I will be using the Account object and from there it will need to pull "Total" from a custom object. The custom child object can have multiple Totals for each account.
The issue I am trying to figure out is, how am I suppose to get the sum displayed. Master-Detail can not be created so it will be a lookup, and I can not use a formula since "Sum" is not available, and the data is "Read-only" so there is no editability. I am thinking of learning how to write triggers and for that total to be created and displayed.
Is this the right path? Am I missing something? Also, if I am understanding what the docs correctly, since there is no way for the user to edit, delete, update, and we are updating the data from our SQL DB then how would the trigger fire when the user is read only?
Thanks for any advice!
Edits:

We get a file then add that to our SQL Server db, after which we run a process that will take that data from our SQL Server db and add that to Salesforce.
We have set the custom object so that it is public read only in the shared setting, so when a user accesses the child records they are only able to read. Since the data is received every day even if they made edits they would be over written, so there is not point in having it be editable.
When I go into the custom object to add the MD relationship, due to there already being records associated with the object I am suppose to change an existing lookup to Account type to the MD. When I do that I get the Error that tells me "Cannot Create Master-Detail Relationship" I have tried this on the existing and new ones but I am still getting the same error.
As for Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary I will need to talk with IT before I can add anything.


I get the feeling that we're missing a fair amount of important details here. Going into more detail about that SQL DB you mentioned seems important (are you using an external object? Or maybe you have some other process to get that data into Salesforce?). What makes you say that the data is "read-only"? Why can't a M-D relationship be established? Please [edit] your question to clarify those points.

and if it does turn out that you need a trigger to do the rollup, your first port of call should be the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary package. It'd generate the trigger(s) and the test class(es) for you, and handles edge cases that you (and almost everyone else who tries to roll their own rollup solution) would almost certainly miss.

@DerekF added the responses to you questions.

Since you want the information specifically in the headline bar, the answer would be "yes, you want to use a trigger." Whether or not it's DLRS, Rollup Helper, another AppExchange app or open source app, or something you develop inhouse, the point is that the values would be calculated when the SQL Server creates/updates the accounts. Triggers don't run when a user views a record, only when a record is modified in the database. These modifications will appear to have come from the SQL Server DB integration user, rather than the user viewing the record.
On the other hand, if you relax your requirements a bit, you have lots of options. You could place a report on the page layout, add a Lightning Component to a record page, create a Record Quick Action that could display the summary, and so on. The only real consideration is whether or not you'd like to have this information on the account record directly as a field value or not. Having a field value gives you options like using the value in a formula, running reports without including the child records, etc.
